# Uncaught TypeError: axios.ad is not a function in vue script

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js

I'm having this error with my vue script, this are the files i'm using
Can't find the error reported with the axios.ad (favoriteAd.vue).
It's basically a favourite feature using:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/implement-a-favoriting-feature-using-laravel-and-vue-js#comments-section
(replacing post with ad)

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('favorite', require('./components/FavoriteAd.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#favorite'
});
```

**favoriteAd.vue**

```
 <template>
<span>
    <a href="#" v-if="isFavorited" @click.prevent="unFavorite(ad)">
        <i  class="fa fa-heart"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#" v-else @click.prevent="favorite(ad)">
        <i  class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
    </a>
</span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['ad', 'favorited'],

    data: function() {
        return {
            isFavorited: '',
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.isFavorited = this.isFavorite ? true : false;
    },

    computed: {
        isFavorite() {
            return this.favorited;
        },
    },

    methods: {
        favorite(ad) {
            console.log(ad);
            axios.ad('/favorite/'+ad) // this is the error line
                .then(response => this.isFavorited = true)
                .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
        },

        unFavorite(ad) {
            axios.ad('/unfavorite/'+ad)
                .then(response => this.isFavorited = false)
                .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
        }
    }
}
```

**view**

```
@if (Auth::check())
 <favorite
    :ad={{ $aviso->id }}
    :favorited={{ $aviso->favorited() ? 'true' : 'false' }}
></favorite>   
@endif
```

Comment: axios doesn't have a method named `ad`. What are you expecting `axios.ad(...)` to do?

Comment: favorite() and unFavorite() both accepts the ad prop as arguments. Using Axios, i make a POST request to the routes (laravel controller routes)

Comment: shouldn't you call `axios.post`? If you are trying to make a post request?

Comment: that's correct! post your answer so i can vote it! thanks

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this question as it seems like it was just a typographical error that is unlikely to be helpful to future readers

Answer (score -2):

You never included axios in your app. Try `npm install axios` then `require('./axios')` on the app.js file. Also, according to the axios reference manual, there's no method named `ad`.

Comment: window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';